# How to customize the output of node content in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming, drupal-templates

I am looking to customize the templated output of the $content variable in node.tpl.php Can you tell me how I could achieve this? Is is possible with another template file?

The reason for this is to achieve AJAX pagination thus I need an ID on node_body and also to pull out the paging nav from this same DIV.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete the $content variablee from node.tpl.php and use the separate fields of $node.
You can view the fields with print_r($node)

Answer (score 1):

Copy the node.tpl file and rename it to node-**contenttypename**.tpl.php.
After doing this you can print the fields using this code

> print $node->field_name[0]['view'] ?>

to print body use this code

> print strip_tags($node->content ['body']['#value']);

to print gallery use this code or you can use views

> print if($node->field_gallery[0]['view']==null){ print " ";  }
>   else
>  {
>
> foreach ((array)$node->field_gallery as $item) {  print $item['view']

i hope you can get ideas using this code.

You can see example from this live site http://www.richtown.ae/?q=content/most-wanted-property-one-bed-residences-dial-0555456012-0

Thanks
http://www.richtown.ae

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create another template file for that particular content type.
using naming convention **node-[content-type-name].tpl.php** 
Naming convention of template file is very much important in Drupal. Put this file into templates folder of theme directory.
and print $node and replace $content variable with the fields you want.